# Using $scope into a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

What I expect from below code is it would bind $scope.as . But nothing is displaying and no error is shown in console

```
var testModule = angular.module('testmodule', [])
.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, mser) {
  mser.aa();
 })
.service('mser', function($scope /* Would $scope be here */) {
  this.aa = function(){
  $scope.as = "hello mars"
 }});
```

Comment: Why you want to use `$scope` in service?

Comment: @Satpal bro i m learning angular and stuck at this point

Comment: @sam Really bad idea to use scope in service. Adding scope to your service  increases angular watchers with every single instance you call from controller, making app slow (more than 2000 watchers : angular gets slower and is visible on browser) .

Service is no longer needed at this point because, just add another function/ move service logic in controller.

As long as you are playing with angular - sky is the limit, have a ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use $scope in service you should use it in your controller it is used to glue controller and DOM. Since services are injected in controllers so there is no individual existence of a service.

Comment: can i use $http ?

Comment: Yes you can since it is a service.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `$scope` in service. You can simply `return` data from service and bind to `$scope` variable in controller

```
var testModule = angular.module('testmodule', [])
.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, mser) {
    $scope.as = mser.aa();
 }).service('mser', function() {
    this.aa = function(){
        return "hello mars"
    }   
});
```

You should read [Injecting $scope into an angular service function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function)

Answer (score 0):

`$scope` object is basically used to **`glue together`** the `view` and the `controller` of your angular application. 
It does not make much sense to pass it into a service.
Services are singleton objects used to share data among several **`controllers`**,**`directives`**,**`filters`** etc.

**Some changes need to be made in your code :**

**1.** Instead of using `$scope` in service used it in controller.

**2.** Return the object from the service and get it into the controller inside a `$scope` object.

Based on the approach described above, you can change your code like this **:**

**controller :**

```
var testModule = angular.module('testmodule', [])
.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, mser) {
  $scope.as = mser.aa();
})
.service('mser', function() {
  this.aa = function(){
    return "hello mars";
}});
```

**view :**

```
<span>{{::as}}</span>
```